# Ubuntu 20.04 NVidia X Server Settings only showing PRIME Profiles

Tags: display, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I have installed the nvidia 435 drivers for my machine. When I try to open NVidia settings to configure multiple displays, I only see PRIME Profiles. I'm expecting to see a lot more settings to be able to configure the graphics card. I'm new to Ubuntu and have tried reinstalling nvidia 435 a few different ways with no luck.

[image: NVidia Settings screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and was not able to solve it even after a reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04. But the NVIDIA driver was working fine on Ubuntu 18.04 and pop OS 20.04.

I guessed the problem must due to the new feature in Ubuntu 20.04 where during the Ubuntu installer installs the NVIDIA driver during the installation of the OS. So, I reinstalled Ubuntu again on my system after unchecking the option to install third-party software for graphics and WiFi and additional media formats. Then I manually installed the NVIDIA driver post installation of Ubuntu using the GUI as I did for my 18.04 installation.

Now all the options in NVIDIA X server settings are displayed.

Since I am a newbie to Linux, I was not able to find why this error happened during installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu for Wayland or Gnome with Wayland then also the nvidia-settings will show the Prime Profiles option only. This seems like a bug for proprietary Nvidia drivers using Wayland windows manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To fix it, I chose "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" and rebooted. I ran `nvidia-settings` on Terminal and still only had PRIME profiles. I chose "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)" and rebooted. When I ran `nvidia-settings` again, the whole settings menu appeared. Going into Settings > About indicates that NVIDIA is being used as graphics.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA Driver 470 installed via GUI.